# Convert nvprof nvidia profile to csv

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvidia

I can create either an `nvprof` or `csv` profile from the CUDA nvprof tool using the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html).

I have now created an `nvprof` type profile of an important event in the code. I can analyse it in the `nvpp` visual tool, but I would like to do some other analysis on the data directly. *Is there a way to convert this file into the equivalent csv file type?*

Comment: How hard is the event to I reproduce? The simplest approach might be to just recreate it and profile with the `--csv` option on. Otherwise I suspect you can get at the CSV data via [SQLite exprt](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-tutorial/sqlite-export-csv/).

Comment: @tera Very hard, but I figured out that the csv option doesn't give me what i want anyway.